# Equivalance testing when one of two (paired) samples has high variance

Tags: statistical-significance, equivalence, tost

I have two paired samples of data that include the same number of observations (N = 878). My aim is to show that the mean difference between sample one and sample two is *not* statistically significant.

Therefore, I applied a test of equivalence for two paired samples, more precisely the *two one-sided t-tests (TOST)* approach. Here, the test hypotheses are as follows:

- **H0:** The difference between the means is outside the equivalence interval.
- **H1:** The difference between the means is inside the equivalence interval.

I would accordingly like to reject the null hypothesis and selected an lower and upper bound as follows: mean difference between both samples plus/minus 10%.

**Problem:**
The problem is, as I see it, that while the mean between both samples is very small (-0.0244 for V1 and -0.034 for V2) given the means of sample one and sample two, I fail to reject the null hypothesis for both instances due to the much higher variance in the sample two.

**Questions:**

1. Would you agree that my assumption is right, meaning that I fail to reject the null hypothesis due to the high variance in sample two?
2. Is there any alternative test or possibility to show that the mean difference between both samples is very low given their absolute numbers (shown on the y-axis of the plot below)?

[image]

Comment: A scatterplot (with a 1:1 line) might be useful to illustrate your points.